# Best way to move from unordered_map with unique_ptr values

Tags: c++, c++17, move

I have a map like this

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<V>> map;
```

I want to eventually run a function on all the remaining `V` in the map, so I do the following:

```
for (auto&& [_, v] : map) {
  func(std::move(v));
}
```

This works, but I've been naively assuming the compiler would ignore the key values, since they aren't used in the for loop.  Now I'm thinking the iterator is yielding `const std::string` as the first argument, so really there's a lot of unnecessary string building going on.  What exactly happens here (regarding the key values)? Is there a way to avoid any string copying?

Comment: Aren't there no string copies? Both `_` and `v` are references on map's actual element.

Comment: Here's a nifty little trick you can use to figure out these kinds of questions all by yourself, and, as an extra-special bonus, learn a little bit more C++. Create your own class that logs all invocations of its copy/move constructors, use that class as a key for a map with some sample values, execute the same identical loop, over the map, and see if any copying takes place. Now, you've answered your own question, here, and learned some valuable C++ skills!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: thank you! I did try that originally, but making the custom type work as a key took me down a rabbit-hole of defining the equality operator and a hasher, and how to make the (existing) map initialization work [where keys were string literals]. In the end I thought SO would know better :)

Comment: And what's wrong with that? Now you have a better understanding of how unordered associative containers work. That's a good thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the C++ standard, [stmt.ranged] specifies that a range-based for loop has equivalent semantics to a certain ordinary for loop. In your case, this is:

```
{
    auto &&__range = map ;
    auto __begin = __range.begin() ;
    auto __end = __range.end() ;
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin ) {
        auto&& [_, v] = *__begin;
        func(std::move(v));
    }
}
```

(Notice that the expression or *braced-init-list* on the right hand side of `:` becomes the initializer for `auto &&__range`, and the declarator or structured binding on the left hand side of `:` is initialized with `*__begin`. This is how the general transformation works.)

In this full form, we can see exactly what is happening. Every time the iterator is dereferenced, it just yields a reference to the (`string`, `unique_ptr`) pair that is stored inside the map. Then the structured binding declaration makes `_` an lvalue referring to that `string`, and `v` an lvalue referring to that `unique_ptr`. Finally, `std::move` converts the lvalue into an rvalue and that rvalue is passed into `func`. No string copy is made.

Answer (score 2):

Dereferencing the iterator for `std::unordered_map` returns references. And then, structured bindings with `auto&&` point to a reference, so no copies are made.

One tool I like to use for this kind of thing is C++ Insights. [For this example](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPHVub3JkZXJlZF9tYXA+CiNpbmNsdWRlIDxzdHJpbmc+CiNpbmNsdWRlIDx1dGlsaXR5PgojaW5jbHVkZSA8bWVtb3J5PgoKdGVtcGxhdGU8dHlwZW5hbWUgVD4Kdm9pZCBmdW5jKFQpOwoKaW50IG1haW4oKXsKICBzdGQ6OnVub3JkZXJlZF9tYXA8c3RkOjpzdHJpbmcsIHN0ZDo6dW5pcXVlX3B0cjxpbnQ+PiBtYXA7CiAgZm9yIChhdXRvJiYgW18sIHZdIDogbWFwKSB7CiAgICBmdW5jKHN0ZDo6bW92ZSh2KSk7CiAgfQp9&insightsOptions=cpp17&std=cpp17&rev=1.0), we can see how all variables are references and there are no copies are instantiated in the loop:

```cpp
int main()
{
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<int> > map = ...;
  {
    std::unordered_map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, ...> & __range1 = map;
    std::__detail::_Node_iterator<...> __begin1 = __range1.begin();
    std::__detail::_Node_iterator<...> __end1 = __range1.end();
    for(; std::__detail::operator!=(__begin1, __end1); __begin1.operator++()) 
    {
      std::pair<const std::basic_string<...>, std::unique_ptr<int, ...> & __operator11 = __begin1.operator*();
      const std::basic_string<...>& _ = std::get<0UL>(__operator11);
      std::unique_ptr<int, ...>& v = std::get<1UL>(__operator11);
      func(std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >(std::move(v)));
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about C++ insights!